# tkinter how to detect if window lowers (.lower() method)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.9

I want to detect that to make a custom titlebar to my application with a Label, when in the background it's color will be changed as it is in normal windows, to change the color of the label I of course need too find a way to detect when lowered or when it's not in topmost protocol ...

Comment: I'll make a slight change to my example to include a `lift` and `lower` capacity.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to determine there is no 100% guaranteed way to do this.  The best approach I have found is to bind the `<Configure>` event to the root window of your application.  Here is what the [Tcl manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.html#M12) has to say about the Configure event:

"A Configure event is sent to a window whenever its size, position, or border width changes, and sometimes when it has changed position in the stacking order."

I successfully used something similar in a recent application (it always worked as far as I can tell) but the word "sometimes" in the documentation did not leave me with a good feeling.

Comment: can you show me also a little example please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `Configure` usage.

`bind` is used to read and display info about window

All other main window methods are also available.

A `lift` and `lower` control is added using keyboard F1 (lift) and F2 (lower)
on selected window.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def scroll( ev ):
    print(
        ev.widget.winfo_x(),
        ev.widget.winfo_y(),
        ev.widget.winfo_width(),
        ev.widget.winfo_height() )

def lift( ev ):
    ev.widget.lift()

def lower( ev):
    ev.widget.lower()

master = tk.Tk()
master.title( 'Tk' )

child = tk.Tk( )
child.title( 'Toplevel' )
    
master.bind("<Configure>", scroll)
child.bind("<Configure>", scroll)

master.bind( "<F1>", lift )
master.bind( "<F2>", lower )

child.bind( "<F1>", lift )
child.bind( "<F2>", lower )

master.mainloop()
```